# Mysql Incorrect String Value

Tags: php, mysql

I have just met a problem while adding some text to mysql db (version  5.0.83 ) through PHP  When I try to add text including Turkish characters Mysql throws error "incorrect string value". What makes the problem more interesting is that if there is one Turkish character in the text string Mysql accepts it but if number of the characters in the string are more than one it gives error.

What is the possible reason of this error?

UPDATE:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cat_communicative` (
`parent_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`child_of` tinytext,
`level_num` int(10) default NULL,
`category_title` tinytext,
`category_file_name` tinytext,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;
```

I am trying to add text to "category-title"

Comment: do u have ' (Apostrophe) in the saving text?

Comment: Please add the example queries you are running.  Also provide the DB and table schema.

Comment: @TilT: Nope, no apastrophe in text

Comment: There are several places in your MySql/php configuration that character encoding can cause trouble. The connections between the two have to set properly, as well as the database and php.

Comment: Any example insert text?

Comment: @SOliver: even two characters such as "üü" cause problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out php's **strtolower()** function causes problem if you have multi-bite characters. Using **mb_strtolower** will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

I've changed the character set of the column to cp850, a more accommodating character set and more importantly accepts Turkish characters.

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cat_communicative` (
    `parent_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `child_of` tinytext,
    `level_num` int(10) default NULL,
    `category_title` tinytext CHAR SET cp850,
    `category_file_name` tinytext,
     PRIMARY KEY  (`parent_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;
```

[Turkish-compatible character sets](http://www.eki.ee/letter/chardata.cgi?lang=tr+Turkish&script=latin)